# how to set default date to first Sat after today in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am coding an application for events and I disabled all days except Sats in my case 
and it works perfect but I am getting a problem how to set initial date for the first Sat after today if it's not Sat or today if it's Sat as  default value in dataPicker
also how I can disable all Days before today even Sats.
here is my code

```
DateTime _dateTime=DateTime.now();

            showDatePicker(
                context: context,
                initialDate:_dateTime.weekday == 1||_dateTime.weekday == 2||_dateTime.weekday == 3||_dateTime.weekday == 4||_dateTime.weekday == 5  ? DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, 1) :  _dateTime,
                firstDate: DateTime(2019),
                lastDate: DateTime(2020),
              selectableDayPredicate: (val)=> val.weekday == 1 ||val.weekday == 2 ||val.weekday == 3 ||val.weekday == 4 || val.weekday == 5 ? false : true,

            );
```

this code works perfect but it make default date time is the first day of year as default date if today is not Sat.
could you please help in this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As I conclude from your question, here are your requirements :**

how to :

- disabled all days except Sats
- also how I can disable all Days before today even Sats
- set initial date for the first Sat after today if it's not Sat
- or today if it's Sat as default value in dataPicker

#### 1. How to Disable days

```dart
  bool defineSelectable(DateTime val) {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    // disabled all days before today
    if (val.isBefore(now)) {
      return false;
    }
    // disabled all days except Sats
    switch (val.weekday) {
      case saturday:
        return true;
        break;
      default:
        return false;
    }
  }

  void handleButton(context) async {
    DateTime chosenDate = await showDatePicker(
      ...
      selectableDayPredicate: defineSelectable,
    );
  }
```

#### 2. How to Initiate Date

```dart
  int daysToAdd(int todayIndex, int targetIndex) {
    if (todayIndex < targetIndex) { // jump to target day in same week
      return targetIndex - todayIndex;
    } else if (todayIndex > targetIndex) { // must jump to next week
      return 7 + targetIndex - todayIndex;
    } else {
      return 0; // date is matched
    }
  }

  DateTime defineInitialDate() {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    int dayOffset = daysToAdd(now.weekday, saturday);
    return now.add(Duration(days: dayOffset));
  }

  void handleButton(context) async {
    DateTime chosenDate = await showDatePicker(
      ...
      initialDate: defineInitialDate(),
      ...
    );
  }
```

### 3. Full Code

You may look into this repo and build it locally [TimePickerScreen](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_tricky_layout/blob/master/lib/g_screen/timePicker.dart)

### 4. Demo

[image: Demo]